# Prevent org-hide-emphasis-markers to modify headers

Tags: org-mode

I am trying to set org-hide-emphasis-markers to t but when I do so the headers are messed up

With org-hide-emphasis-markers disabled

```
* A
** B
*** C
**** D
```

With org-hide-emphasis-markers enabled

```
* A
** B
* C    <- Bold asterisk
** D  <- Bold 2 asterisks
```

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: It worked for me until very recently, so I think it is a bug. It is mentioned on the org-mode mailing list too: [1](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-11/msg00363.html), [2](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-11/msg00346.html), and maybe [3](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2017-12/msg00017.html)

Comment: Try updating your org-mode; the update dated 20171205 seems to have fixed this problem for me.